# Combine the rotation matrix?

Tags: opengl-es, matrix

I found a good article about rotation matrix:

http://db-in.com/blog/2011/04/cameras-on-opengl-es-2-x/

everything works as I expected,but:

```
void matrixRotateX(float degrees, mat4 matrix)
void matrixRotateY(float degrees, mat4 matrix)
void matrixRotateZ(float degrees, mat4 matrix)
```

generated three matrices, the article says I need to multiply them together, I mean if this is c++ I could use `matx * maty * matz` right? but this `mat4` is just `float[16]`, which I don't know how to combine.

Comment: the link you supplied doesn't work.

Comment: can you open the cached version? http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:db-in.com/blog/2011/04/cameras-on-opengl-es-2-x/

Comment: I don't want to come across too blunt, but: You should not tacke 3D programming without a solid understanding of basic linear algebra, i.e. how to work with vectors and matrices. Some undergraduate math textbook on linear algebra should be on your to-read list, as well as a computer graphics math primer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Matrices](http://db-in.com/blog/2011/04/cameras-on-opengl-es-2-x/#matrices) chapter in the article you refer has a formula for matrix multiplication. Also you could check [glm](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ogl-math/) if you want to use **operator*** for matrix multiplication(and other cool stuff).

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, you should read this artical:

[OpenGL transformation](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html)

Understanding it thoroughly is important for complex operations.

Answer (score 0):

Function "matrixMultiply()" in the article you referenced, performs matrix multiplication for you and takes care of the special 1D matrix type mat4 you are using:

```
void matrixMultiply(mat4 m1, mat4 m2, mat4 result)
{
    // First Column
    result[0] = m1[0]*m2[0] + m1[4]*m2[1] + m1[8]*m2[2] + m1[12]*m2[3];
    result[1] = m1[1]*m2[0] + m1[5]*m2[1] + m1[9]*m2[2] + m1[13]*m2[3];
    result[2] = m1[2]*m2[0] + m1[6]*m2[1] + m1[10]*m2[2] + m1[14]*m2[3];
    result[3] = m1[3]*m2[0] + m1[7]*m2[1] + m1[11]*m2[2] + m1[15]*m2[3];
 
    // Second Column
    result[4] = m1[0]*m2[4] + m1[4]*m2[5] + m1[8]*m2[6] + m1[12]*m2[7];
    result[5] = m1[1]*m2[4] + m1[5]*m2[5] + m1[9]*m2[6] + m1[13]*m2[7];
    result[6] = m1[2]*m2[4] + m1[6]*m2[5] + m1[10]*m2[6] + m1[14]*m2[7];
    result[7] = m1[3]*m2[4] + m1[7]*m2[5] + m1[11]*m2[6] + m1[15]*m2[7];
 
    // Third Column
    result[8] = m1[0]*m2[8] + m1[4]*m2[9] + m1[8]*m2[10] + m1[12]*m2[11];
    result[9] = m1[1]*m2[8] + m1[5]*m2[9] + m1[9]*m2[10] + m1[13]*m2[11];
    result[10] = m1[2]*m2[8] + m1[6]*m2[9] + m1[10]*m2[10] + m1[14]*m2[11];
    result[11] = m1[3]*m2[8] + m1[7]*m2[9] + m1[11]*m2[10] + m1[15]*m2[11];
 
    // Fourth Column
    result[12] = m1[0]*m2[12] + m1[4]*m2[13] + m1[8]*m2[14] + m1[12]*m2[15];
    result[13] = m1[1]*m2[12] + m1[5]*m2[13] + m1[9]*m2[14] + m1[13]*m2[15];
    result[14] = m1[2]*m2[12] + m1[6]*m2[13] + m1[10]*m2[14] + m1[14]*m2[15];
    result[15] = m1[3]*m2[12] + m1[7]*m2[13] + m1[11]*m2[14] + m1[15]*m2[15];
}
```

Matrix multiplication using 2D arrays can be done in three nested for-loops.
A similar solution for your mat4 type is left as an exercise. OK?